# Apache cannot access custom directory

Tags: apache, directory

I am using `apache 2.4` and `ubuntu 15.10`.
I want to change default `/var/www/html/` directory for my files into `/home/myuser/mydir/`. I know there are many tutorials, but it doesn't seem to work.

I changed `000-default.conf`:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost     
# DocumentRoot /var/www/html 
DocumentRoot /home/myuser/mydir
# <Directory /var/www/html>
<Directory /home/myuser/mydir>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I changed `default-ssl.conf`:

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

# DocumentRoot /var/www/html
DocumentRoot /home/myuser/mydir
```

I changed `apache.conf`:

```
# <Directory /var/www/html>
<Directory /home/myuser/mydir>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`ls -l` in `/home/myuser/mydir` is solid: `-rwxrwxrwx`

If I restart apache2 and access "localhost" in my browser I get:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Step 1 is looking at the error_log. The message will tell you if it's a filesystem permissions issue or Apache configuration issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make /home/myuser/ world readable and world executable.

Comment: It wasn't enough to edit permissions on /home/myuser/mydir, I had to edit /home/mydir/ as well. Silly me. Thanks for help!